# i am getting errors when using the foreach command. it constantly gives the error of '{ required'

Tags: foreach, stata, local, brackets

I am using the following do file to replicate the data of banerjee et al.(2014). Though at the //2) i get an error after the foreach command that says '{ required'. Does someone know what is wrong with the code.

```
clear all
set more off
pause on

//data directory
global datadir "C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\documenten\Universiteit\Bachelor_Thesis\Data\Replication package American_Economic_Association\Storage"

//output directory
global outputdir "C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\documenten\Universiteit\Bachelor_Thesis\Data\Replication package American_Economic_Association\Output"

log using Log_replication.smc1

//controls for baseline variables
global area_controls "area_pop_base area_debt_total_base area_business_total_base area_exp_pc_mean_base area_literate_head_base area_literate_base"

cd "$outputdir"

***************************************************************************
***************** Table 1A: Baseline Summary Statistics *******************
***************************************************************************

use "$datadir/2013-0533_data_baseline.dta", clear

local hh_composition "hh_size adult children male_head head_age head_noeduc"
local credit_access "spandana othermfi bank informal anyloan"
local loan_amt "spandana_amt othermfi_amt bank_amt informal_amt anyloan_amt"
local self_emp_activ "total_biz female_biz female_biz_pct"
local businesses "bizrev bizexpense bizinvestment bizemployees hours_weekbiz"
local businesses_allHH "bizrev_allHH bizexpense_allHH bizinvestment_allHH bizemployees_allHH hours_weekbiz_allHH"
local consumption "total_exp_mo nondurable_exp_mo durables_exp_mo home_durable_index"

local allvars "`hh_composition' `credit_access' `loan_amt' `self_emp_activ' `businesses' `businesses_allHH' `consumption'"

//1) Generate variables for business outcomes for all households (replacing each variable with 0 for households without a business)
foreach var in `businesses' {
    gen `var'_allHH=`var'
    replace `var'_allHH=0 if total_biz==0
    }

//2)Create summary statistics table:    
scalar drop _all
foreach var of $allvars {
    sum `var' if treatment==0
    scalar `var'_N=r(N)
    scalar `var'_c=r(mean)
    scalar sd`var'_c=r(sd)
    reg `var' treatment, cluster(areaid)
    mat beta`var'=e(b)
    scalar `var'_d=beta`var'{1,1}
    test treatment=0
    scalar pval_`var'=r(p)
    matrix Table1A = {nullmat(Table1A) \ `var'_N, `var'_c, sd`var'_c, `var'_d, pval`var'}
}
matrix rownames Table1A = `allvars'
matrix colnames Table1A = Obs Control_mean Control_sd Difference p_val
mat2txt, matrix(Table1A) saving("$outputdir/table1a.txt") replace
```

i have tried to change $allvars  to `allvars' but that didnot solve the issue. in the original do file the command is as follows:

```
foreach var of varlist `allvars' {
```

Though then the error is "varlist required"

Comment: use the same construction as in step one (i.e. foreach var in `allvars')

Comment: @langlang is correct. You defined `allvars` as local and you have no such global.

Comment: It is not good practice to show us all your code -- with datasets we can't access -- when the code problem is to with one small fragment. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example